# Vectorize for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jit, numba

I have a following loop where I am calculating `softmax` transform for batches of different sizes as below

```
import numpy as np 
def softmax(Z,arr):
    """
    :param Z:  numpy array of any shape (output from hidden layer)
    :param arr: numpy array of any shape (start, end)
    :return A: output of multinum_logit(Z,arr), same shape as Z
    :return cache: returns Z as well, useful during back propagation
    """
    A = np.zeros(Z.shape)
    for i in prange(len(arr)):
        shiftx = Z[:,arr[i,1]:arr[i,2]+1] - np.max(Z[:,int(arr[i,1]):int(arr[i,2])+1])
        A[:,arr[i,1]:arr[i,2]+1] = np.exp(shiftx)/np.exp(shiftx).sum()
    cache = Z
    return A,cache
```

Since this for loop is not vectorized it is the bottleneck in my code. What is a possible solution to make it faster. I have tried using `@jit` of `numba` which makes it little faster but not enough. I was wondering if there is another way to make it faster or vectorize/parallelize it.

Sample input data for the function

```
Z = np.random.random([1,10000])
arr = np.zeros([100,3])
arr[:,0] = 1
temp = int(Z.shape[1]/arr.shape[0])
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    arr[i,1] = i*temp
    arr[i,2] = (i+1)*temp-1
arr = arr.astype(int)
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to stress here that my number of class is varying. For example batch 1 has say 10 classes, batch 2 may have 15 classes. Therefore I am passing an array arr which keeps track of the which rows belong to batch1 and so on. These batches are different than the batches in traditional neural network framework

In the above example `arr` keeps track of starting index and end index of rows. So the denominator in the softmax function will be sum of only those observations whose index lie between the starting and ending index.

Comment: 1) The array order has a significant influence on performance. In a C ordered array the last dim changes fastest. So I would recommend zo exchange (dim0 and dim1 in your z-Array). 2) If your arr array is realy that regular you can integrate it in the softmax function, using only loops. That should give another speedup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vectorized softmax function. It's the implementation of an assignment from Stanford's cs231n course on conv nets.

The function takes in optimizable parameters, input data, targets, and a regularizer. (You can ignore the regularizer as that references another class exclusive to some cs231n assignments).

It returns a loss and gradients of the parameters.

```
def softmax_loss_vectorized(W, X, y, reg):
  """
  Softmax loss function, vectorized version.
  Inputs and outputs are the same as softmax_loss_naive.
  """
  # Initialize the loss and gradient to zero.

  loss = 0.0
  dW = np.zeros_like(W)

  num_train = X.shape[0]

  scores = X.dot(W)

  shift_scores = scores - np.amax(scores,axis=1).reshape(-1,1)

  softmax = np.exp(shift_scores)/np.sum(np.exp(shift_scores), axis=1).reshape(-1,1)

  loss = -np.sum(np.log(softmax[range(num_train), list(y)]))

  loss /= num_train

  loss += 0.5* reg * np.sum(W * W)

  dSoftmax = softmax.copy()

  dSoftmax[range(num_train), list(y)] += -1

  dW = (X.T).dot(dSoftmax)
  dW = dW/num_train + reg * W

  return loss, dW
```

For comparison's sake, here is a naive (non-vectorized) implementation of the same method.

```
def softmax_loss_naive(W, X, y, reg):
  """
  Softmax loss function, naive implementation (with loops)
  Inputs have dimension D, there are C classes, and we operate on minibatches
  of N examples.
  Inputs:
  - W: A numpy array of shape (D, C) containing weights.
  - X: A numpy array of shape (N, D) containing a minibatch of data.
  - y: A numpy array of shape (N,) containing training labels; y[i] = c means
    that X[i] has label c, where 0 <= c < C.
  - reg: (float) regularization strength
  Returns a tuple of:
  - loss as single float
  - gradient with respect to weights W; an array of same shape as W
  """

  loss = 0.0
  dW = np.zeros_like(W)

  num_train = X.shape[0]
  num_classes = W.shape[1]

  for i in xrange(num_train):
      scores = X[i].dot(W)

      shift_scores = scores - max(scores)

      loss_i = -shift_scores[y[i]] + np.log(sum(np.exp(shift_scores)))
      loss += loss_i
      for j in xrange(num_classes):
          softmax = np.exp(shift_scores[j])/sum(np.exp(shift_scores))
          if j==y[i]:

              dW[:,j] += (-1 + softmax) * X[i]
          else:
              dW[:,j] += softmax *X[i]

  loss /= num_train

  loss += 0.5 * reg * np.sum(W * W)

  dW /= num_train + reg * W

  return loss, dW
```

[Source](https://github.com/arikanev/cs231n-solutions/blob/master/assignment1/cs231n/classifiers/softmax.py)

Comment: I forgot to stress here that my number of class is varying. For example batch 1 has say 10 classes, batch 2 may have 15 classes. Therefore I am passing an array arr which keeps track of the which rows belong to batch1 and so on. These batches are different than the batches in traditional neural network framework

Comment: If you run softmax separately per batch, this option could work

Comment: I thought in the above code I am doing that. I am calculating vectorized softmax for particular batches of rows

Comment: Yeah, you are doing that in the above code. I wasn't sure why you added the extra comment - I thought you suggested it changed the validity of my answer.

Comment: I was looking for something to make this for loop faster. I know it can't be vectorized in the way you have suggested. Based on your answer it felt like my question was not clear therefore I appended my question

Comment: I see, maybe I didn't understand your question then. If so, sorry! Hope you find a good answer.